# PHPで乱数から最大値、最小値、平均値を出力

Tags: php

```
<?php
for($i＝0:$i<30:$i++){
   prnt(rand().'〈br〉'):
}
?>
```

ここから最大値、最小値、平均値を出力したいのですが、どうやればいいですか？

Answer (score 1):

randの値を配列に入れ min(),max(),array_sum()を使うのが良いかと。

```
$data = array();
for($i＝0;$i<30;$i++){
    $data[] = rand();
}

$min = min($data);
$max = max($data);
$average = array_sum($data)/count($data);
```